# Who is right here on `std::initializer_list`? clang++ or g++?

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer, clang++, stdinitializerlist

After fighting for long with a program where I couldn't get `std::initializer_list` logic working as expected I ended up with a small case in which I discovered that `clang++` 6.0.1 and `g++` 8.2.0 are both compiling, but with different semantic.

Which one is the correctly implementing the standard? I tried to understand the rules myself by reading pertinent sections but my brain exploded in the attempt...

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Value {
    int i;
    std::vector<Value> *v;
    Value() : i(0), v(nullptr) {}
    Value(int x) : i(x), v(nullptr) {}

    template<typename T>
    Value(const std::vector<T>& x)
      : v(new std::vector<Value>(x.begin(), x.end())) { }

    Value(std::initializer_list<Value> L)
      : Value(std::vector<Value>(L)) { }

    void dump(int indent = 0) {
        if (v) {
            printf("%*s[\n", indent, "");
            for (int i=0,n=v->size(); i<n; i++) {
                (*v)[i].dump(indent + 4);
            }
            printf("%*s]\n", indent, "");
        } else {
            printf("%*s%i\n", indent, "", i);
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    Value x; printf("x:\n"); x.dump(); printf("---\n\n");
    Value y1 = x; printf("y1:\n"); y1.dump(); printf("---\n\n");
    Value y2 = {x}; printf("y2:\n"); y2.dump(); printf("---\n\n");
    Value y3; y3 = {x}; printf("y3:\n"); y3.dump(); printf("---\n\n");
    Value y4; y4 = {{x}}; printf("y4:\n"); y4.dump(); printf("---\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

In the specific `g++` initializes `y2` as a list of values (`v` pointer gets initialized), while `clang++` instead just calls the copy constructor on `x`.

Live examples:

- [g++](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2Zg26lTUPirudLAn)
- [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mFNR5ZLyT0TGP36k)

Comment: What C++ version are you building as (for either compiler)?

Comment: when braces are used initialization list is preferred.