# Nested vector<any> bug

Tags: c++, c++17

This code results in an error message:

> libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_any_cast: bad any cast

```
vector<any> A = {vector<any>({1, 2})};
cout << any_cast<int>(any_cast<vector<any>>(A[0])[0]) << endl;
```

I am unable to debug this problem. Note that the following works and correctly outputs 1:

```
vector<any> A = {vector<int>({1, 2})};
cout << any_cast<vector<int>>(A[0])[0] << endl;
```

When I try to find the type of any_cast<vector>(A[0])[0] - which is obviously int - I get the same error message:

```
cout << any_cast<vector<any>>(A[0])[0].type().name() << endl;
```

> libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_any_cast: bad any cast

Comment: Where is `any` defined as a complete type? See [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) relating to template parameter `t`. Maybe I'm missing what you are asking, but there are limitations on what `any` can be.

Comment: Can you `any_cast` something that is not an `any` type?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm doing an algoexpert problem where the input is vector<any>, and the elements are either int or vector<any>. I'm a c++ beginner btw and I've only heard about std::any today, so I don't know what a complete type is.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox No. Except for a pointer to any, which will return a pointer to the type you're casting to.

Comment: I can reproduce this in clang but not gcc. In clang, `A` is copy constructed from `vector<any>({1, 2})` (so is a vector of size 2, `{ any{1}, any{2} }`), but in gcc it is list initialized as a vector of size 1 containing a vector of size 2. So this question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52000082

Comment: @Artyer I'm using clion (which uses clang-tidy). Also, the second code snippet in my question outputs 1, so A[0] is successfully cast into vector<int>. This wouldn't be the case if A was {any{1}, any{2}}.

Comment: @RaunakChhatwal With `vector<int>`, the copy constructor can't be called. With `vector<any>`, clang gets confused and calls the copy constructor instead of the `initializer_list<any>`  constructor. Try printing `A.size()` and `A[0].type().name()` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that your code snippet does not properly match the any_cast with the type that is being casted to.  Not entirely sure, without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but that is what it appears.

You can use the any_cast in an inquiry fashion.  Probably not great for performance, though, because it fails by throwing an exception which is then converted to the predicate returning false.  For non-production code, should be fine.

Here's a `vector<any>` that contains one of:  `vector<any>`, or `int` or `string`.

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::any;
using std::any_cast;
using std::bad_any_cast;
using std::cout;
using std::ostream;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

namespace {

bool is_vector_any(any const& x) {
    try {
        any_cast<vector<any>>(x);
        return true;
    } catch(bad_any_cast const&) {
    }

    return false;
}

bool is_int(any const& x) {
    try {
        any_cast<int>(x);
        return true;
    } catch(bad_any_cast const&) {
    }

    return false;
}

bool is_string(any const& x) {
    try {
        any_cast<string>(x);
        return true;
    } catch(bad_any_cast const&) {
    }

    return false;
}

static
auto operator<<(ostream& out, vector<any> const& v) -> ostream& {
    auto sep = string("");

    for (auto const& x : v) {
        if (is_vector_any(x)) {
            out << sep << "{ " << any_cast<vector<any>>(x) << " }";
        } else if (is_int(x)) {
            out << sep << any_cast<int>(x);
        } else if (is_string(x)) {
            out << sep << any_cast<string>(x);
        } else {
            out << sep << "?";
        }

        sep = " ";
    }

    if (sep == "") {
        out << "(empty)";
    }

    return out;
}

} // anon

int main() {
    vector<any> A = {vector<any>({1, 2})};
    A.push_back(vector<any>({string{"yes"}, string{"no"}, 3}));
    cout << "{ " << A << " }\n";
}
```